# frattini subgroup of group of order $p^4$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group of order $p^4$ ($p$ a prime > 3) with $|Z(G)|=p$ (there are $4$ groups upto isomorphism). I need to ask what are frattini subgroup of these?

Comment: Vipul, do you know explicitly the four isomorphism classes of subgroups with this property? If you do, then writing down representatives in each isomorphism class would be a good place to start. I guess this is an obvious suggestion but I think it's useful. Also, what happens in the case of groups of order $p^3$ for $p$ a prime greater than $3$? (Of course, a group of order $p^2$ for $p$ any prime is abelian and so the condition that the center have order $p$ isn't satisfied.) In fact, a non-abelian $p$-group of order $p^3$ must have center of order $p$ (why?) so we're looking at these groups.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to find out the facts, a computer algebra package like GAP or MAGMA could tell you. For instance typing the following code into MAGMA (which you can do [here](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/)):

```
for i in [1..NumberOfSmallGroups(5^4)] do
   G:=SmallGroup(5^4,i);
   F:=FrattiniSubgroup(G);
   <#Center(G),#F,IsElementaryAbelian(F)>;
end for;
```

shows that the four groups of order $5^4$ with centres of order 5 all have elementary abelian Frattini subgroups of order 25. Of course this may be of little use, depending what you want to know about these groups.